# Store date variable in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to store date values into a variable for future use. Please correct the sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Now_hourly = $(date +%d-%b-%H_%M)    
Now_daily = $(date +%d-%b-daily)    
echo $(Now_hourly)    
echo $(Now_daily)
```

The output should be :
`12-Feb-17_50`
and 
`12-Feb-daily`
But When I run the script, I am getting below error :
`Now_hourly: command not found`
`Now_daily: command not found`

Comment: It's a __FAQ__.  You can't have spaces on either side of `=` while assigning a variable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP expects the reader to _correct the sample script_.

Comment: @Gopu you can get the correct answer by testing everything that reach to your mind..no problem..It is solved :)

Comment: Besides: use curly braces in the echo lines, otherwise Now_hourly will be tried to execute.

Answer (score 53):

you can change the script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
Now_hourly=$(date +%d-%b-%H_%M)    
Now_daily=$(date +%d-%b-daily)    
echo "$Now_hourly"
echo "$Now_daily"
```

I think the problem is spaces around `=`

**output:**

```
12-Feb-12_03
12-Feb-daily
```

Comment: Also, as a generic answer, if your date format may contain spaces, you should keep the format in double quotes, like so -->

Now_hourly=$(date +"%d-%b-%H_%M")